# How to add custom default value to Nullable type when creating table in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to be able to insert null values for specific rows, not by default
For example:
I hope to be able to insert null values for age, but if not specified then it's defaulted with the value 10.

```sql
create table mytable
        (
            age Int null default 10,
            name String
            
        ) ENGINE = MergeTree()
        ORDER BY name
```

result

```
Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 88 ('default') (line 3, col 26): default 10,
            name String
            
        ) ENGINE = MergeTree()
        ORDER BY name. Expected one of: CODEC, TTL, ClosingRoundBracket, Comma, COMMENT, token (version 21.8.10.19 (official build))
```

the [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nullable/) says:
`NULL is the default value for any Nullable type, unless specified otherwise in the ClickHouse server configuration.`

I think I have to find the correct setting on this [page](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/) or I misunderstood the relationship between default values and Nullable type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickHouse has a special syntax `Nullable( <type> )` --> `age Nullable(Int)`

```sql
create table mytable
        (
            age Nullable(Int) default 10,
            name String
            
        ) ENGINE = MergeTree()
        ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thank you this has the correct behavior. I thought that `Nullable(Int)` was the same as `Int NULL`...